# React rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend

I want display a lottery wheel on my hobby project. I found this package in npm 'lottery-wheel' and tried to install it and render it without any success.

I installed it with:

```
npm install lottery-wheel
```

I included it in the component-file:

```
import Wheel from 'lottery-wheel';
```

I want to render it within the div (id: 'wheel'):

```
    render() {
          const wheel = new Wheel({
            el: document.querySelector("#wheel"),
            data: [{
              text: 'apple',
              chance: 20
            }, {
              text: 'banana'
            }, {
              text: 'orange'
            }, {
              text: 'peach'
            }],
            onSuccess(data) {
              console.log(data.text);
            }
          });
    
        return (
                <div id="wheel">
                    {wheel}
                </div>
        );
    }
```

I don't know where to put this when I have a structure llike this ...

```
class Lottery extends Component {

}
```

I can simply get the correct element with document.querySelector("#wheel") but please educate me on a good practice to render components and subcomponents using this main structure (class extends Component)
Thanks!

Comment: As far as render and return is concerned , it is fine to render as you did. Please check your wheel , may be your are doing something wrong there.

Comment: Try using a ref instead of `document.querySelector` https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it's a class or a functional component. In either you can and should place their sub-components in `render()` (after adequate `import`, of course).

In your particular case, your `Wheel` component needs to get an existing DOM element (`el` attribute) to be rendered into, and your `#wheel` element is rendered after the `Wheel` initialization and doesn't exist yet during. The issue is ordering of functions (unfortunately for you, `render()` always comes last).

The simple solutions here would be:
a) create a `#wheel` element in your `index.html` (not recommended since it interferes with the main React concept of rendering the whole App into one `div`);
b) initialize your `Wheel` in a `componentDidMount()` (if you don't know about React lifecycle, read about it - quite fundamental) or its hook equivalent - those are simply executed after `render()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //your initialization here
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes but how in this case? Observing the example it is a 'functional component' riight? So where Do I put it?

I can't put it in render since the div that I need is not even rendered before it
`
render() {
   const wheel = new Wheel({ el=docoment.querySelector("#wheel") bla bla bla})
  return (
    <div id="wheel">
      {wheel}
    </div>
  )
}
`

Comment: Ok solved with componentDidMount(), I must have missed something before because I thought I tried it. 

However, how would I use 'useEffect' when I dont have a functional component?

--> What is the link between the useEffect and the location to render?

Comment: Glad to help :) As I said - it's either a lifecycle function (in class components) OR it's hook equivalent (in functional component). You can't use hooks in class component and lifecycle functions in functional component. If the answer satisfies your answer, please mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ref https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Something along the lines of

```
class Wheel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.wheelRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const wheel = new Wheel({
      el: this.wheelRef.current,
      data: [
        {
          text: 'apple',
          chance: 20,
        },
        {
          text: 'banana',
        },
        {
          text: 'orange',
        },
        {
          text: 'peach',
        },
      ],
      onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data.text);
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.wheelRef} />;
  }
}

export default Wheel;


// Other file 
import Wheel from '../wheel';


render () {
  return <Wheel />
}
```